# no convert function c++

Tags: c++, list

I have this problem constantly
I have defined cours class as an object in a student class and now I cannot save it in an array

[Screenshot of error as presented by IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSqPo.png)

```cpp
   list<student> listStudents;
   FILE* f;

   f= fopen("s.t.h.txt", "r");
    
    for (int i=0;i<cont;i++)
    {
        string arr[4];
        fscanf(f, "%d %s %s ", &arr);


        student  st1;
        st1.stu_id = stoi(arr[0]);
        st1.stu_name = arr[1];
        st1.co_num = stoi(arr[2]);
        st1.co = arr[3];
        listStudents.push_back(st1);
    }; 

     class student {
     public:
    int stu_id;
    string stu_name;
    int co_num;
    course* co;
    int s;
    student(int s);
    int max = 5;}
```

Comment: why you cannot save it in an array? Please explain your problem

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: please post a [mcve].

Comment: `std::string` passed as an argument to `fscanf`? Well, that's an idea.

Comment: Another thing your problem is not that you cannot store the student in the list. One of the problems is this line `st1.co = arr[3];` You cannot just say that a `std::string` now is as `course` you have to convert it somehow

Comment: 'No suitable conversion from "std:string"to “course” exists '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't convert something from a datatype that you've made into a string just by willing it to be so. What you can do is initialize the array into a parent datatype, and then add any of the inheritance tree into the array, because it is an "is a" relationship.

Another option is to create a "getter". This means adding a function in the course object, such as getName(), that returns a string.

The bottom line is that the array is of the string type and the course object is not a string, but a course name might be!

Answer (score 0):

In your linked image error is at line `st1.co = arr[3];`.

`co` is a field whose type is `course *`, and `arr` is an array of `string`. Thus compiler complains because you are trying to set an `course *` with a `string`.

More :

What do you think `fscanf(f, "%d %s %s ", &arr);` will do? If you use C++, then use C++ constructs, aka `cin`...

Comment: thanx 
is for file